# How to avoid writing by hand a massive (switch) case, using a loop or a method

Tags: ruby, loops, switch-statement

I need to set bites per seconds to a range of megabits per seconds, the problems is that the bits goes from 1 bps to 7 Gbps, so the case expression will be massive, is there another way to do this? maybe using a loop, or a method, to avoid write all the cases by hand?

```
                d = event.get("bps")
                f = d.round()

                result = case f
                   when 0..1000000 then 1
                   when 1000001..2000000 then 2
                   when 2000001..3000000 then 3
                   when 3000001..4000000 then 4
                   when 4000001..5000000 then 5
                end
                event.set("range_mbps", result)
```

Comment: Sorry I correct the overlaping and the discontinuity

Comment: Is there a reason why 0 bits are 1 megabit?

Answer (score 1):

You can use two methods.

```
RANGE_SIZE = 1_000_000
```

```
def bit_to_range_id(n)
  return 1 if n.zero?
  ((n-1)/RANGE_SIZE) + 1
end
```

```
def range_id_to_range(id)
  return 0..RANGE_SIZE if id == 1 
  1+(id-1)*RANGE_SIZE..(id)*RANGE_SIZE
end
```

```
b = 36_500_000
id = bit_to_range_id(b)
  #=> 37 
range_id_to_range(id)
  #=> 36000001..37000000
```

```
b = 37_000_000
id = bit_to_range_id(b)
  #=> 37 
range_id_to_range(id)
  #=> 36000001..37000000
```

```
b = 36_000_000
id = bit_to_range_id(b)
  #=> 36 
range_id_to_range(id)
  #=> 35000001..36000000
```

```
b = 0
id = bit_to_range_id(b)
  #=> 1 
range_id_to_range(id)
  #=> 0..1000000
```

```
b = 1_000_000
id = bit_to_range_id(b)
  #=> 1 
range_id_to_range(id)
  #=> 0..1000000
```

Answer (score 1):

One megabit is one million bits, so you can simply divide by one million:

```ruby
result = if f.zero? then 1 else (f-1) / 1_000_000 + 1 end
```